# Would adding extra RAM ease up kswapd processes?

Tags: swap

I've an OpenVZ 7 node and the usage is as follows:

```
Swap Usage: 58% 
RAM Free: 36% of 125.7GB
```

I repeatedly see two kswapd processes firing up, using ~200% CPU collectively:

[image]

Swappiness is set to 37.

I am wondering if adding extra RAM would be beneficial, or if there is anything else I should be doing to calm things down in this area.

Comment: Only add as much RAM as you need.

Comment: kswapd typically runs when the system is low on memory, in order proactively to try and free some before applications stall entirely. So the answer is probably yes, although it would help to provide `cat /proc/154/stack` and `grep . /proc/pressure/*` (assuming a recent kernel with `CONFIG_PSI=y`) to see what it's doing.

Comment: @ChrisDown - thanks.

`# cat /proc/154/stack
[<ffffffffa6a3f27a>] ksm_scan_thread+0x1fa/0x2e0
[<ffffffffa68c8d81>] kthread+0xd1/0xe0
[<ffffffffa6fceeb7>] ret_from_fork_nospec_end+0x0/0x39
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
#`

grep . /proc/pressure/* returns no such file or directory